# Happy birthday to ebooks.SE!

Tags: discussion

Time flies! ebooks.stack exchange is now 10 years old (given or taken some days). When I found this out, my first though was "it's impossible! I remember when we were in Area 51 trying to concoct a good proposal for the group..." But indeed all of this happened a long time ago.

Our site does not get a ton of traffic, maybe because ebooks became so ubiquitous that the need to tweak them for reading is not necessary anymore. But even if the standards settled down, there is still space for some new ideas, and of course for finding out the answers to questions old but still relevant.

Dear readers (in different senses of the word...), let's take some time to celebrate making it to 10 years, share some reflections about our time on the site so far, and think about what we would like to find in the next 10 years!

your faithful moderators: @JasonDown , @Daniel , @mau .

Comment: Congratulations on turning 10!